# How to compare a string and a character array in android?

Tags: android, string, character-arrays

I have a string `"sss"` and a character array `{'s','s','s'}`. I converted the array to string but the message **"both are equal"** is not printed upon comparing them. Why?

```
public class RoughActivity extends Activity 
{
 private Button checkButton;
 private TextView text;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        start();
        }

        private void start() {
            int i;
            checkButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
            text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
            final String question="sss";
            final char answer[]=new char[question.length()];
            for(i=0;i<question.length();i++)
            {
                answer[i]='s';
            }
            checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ //on clicking the button,the text must be filled with "both are equal"
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if(question.equals(answer))
                    {
                        text.setText("both are equal");
                    }


                }});
}
}
```

Comment: you are trying to compare a string with an array of chars which are two very different things..

Answer (score 5):

Create a new string from the char array and compare.

```
If(question.equals(new String(answer)){
}
```

or

```
If(question.equals(answer.toString()){
}
```

Having said that, I can't imagine why you are trying to store answers in char[].

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean equals (Object object)
```

This method compares the specified object to this string and returns true if they are equal. The object must be an instance of string with the same characters in the same order.

> So first you you need to convert it to first into String using toString method.

For ex:

```
String string = charArray.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop.

```
boolean equal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
      if (!question.charAt(i) == answer[i] {
           equal = false;
           break;
      }
 }
```

I think that should work.